# How to get caret x and y position in contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, contenteditable

What is a simple way to get a live caret x and y position? I've seen answers about how to get it's index position, but not x and y that updates as you type. What is the best way to do this with JQuery?

Comment: You need to add a keyup event listener to target the div. Every time a key up event is triggered, you call the method that gets the position.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get contentEditable caret index position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972014/get-contenteditable-caret-index-position)

Comment: @Bren Unfortunately not. I want the x and y position.

Comment: Physical location relative to what, the div, the entire DOM viewport? Are you just trying to get the line and column number?

Comment: @Bren the entire viewport

Comment: Unless you used a monospaced font, I can't imagine how it would be accurate. My first thought would be to have a dummy element that is 1rem dimensions and use javascript to get the physical dimensions of that dummy element. Then refer to the other solution I linked above. Then you'll need to compensate for where the div is located in the viewport and add those values appropriately.

Answer (score -2):

I found this code on a GitHub project. I hope it is what you needed.

```js
// The properties that we copy into a mirrored div.
// Note that some browsers, such as Firefox,
// do not concatenate properties, i.e. padding-top, bottom etc. -> padding,
// so we have to do every single property specifically.
var properties = [
  'boxSizing',
  'width',  // on Chrome and IE, exclude the scrollbar, so the mirror div wraps exactly as the textarea does
  'height',
  'overflowX',
  'overflowY',  // copy the scrollbar for IE

  'borderTopWidth',
  'borderRightWidth',
  'borderBottomWidth',
  'borderLeftWidth',

  'paddingTop',
  'paddingRight',
  'paddingBottom',
  'paddingLeft',

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font
  'fontStyle',
  'fontVariant',
  'fontWeight',
  'fontStretch',
  'fontSize',
  'lineHeight',
  'fontFamily',

  'textAlign',
  'textTransform',
  'textIndent',
  'textDecoration',  // might not make a difference, but better be safe

  'letterSpacing',
  'wordSpacing'
];

var isFirefox = !(window.mozInnerScreenX == null);
var mirrorDivDisplayCheckbox = document.getElementById('mirrorDivDisplay');
var mirrorDiv, computed, style;

getCaretCoordinates = function (element, position) {
  // mirrored div
  mirrorDiv = document.getElementById(element.nodeName + '--mirror-div');
  if (!mirrorDiv) {
    mirrorDiv = document.createElement('div');
    mirrorDiv.id = element.nodeName + '--mirror-div';
    document.body.appendChild(mirrorDiv);
  }

  style = mirrorDiv.style;
  computed = getComputedStyle(element);

  // default textarea styles
  style.whiteSpace = 'pre-wrap';
  if (element.nodeName !== 'INPUT')
    style.wordWrap = 'break-word';  // only for textarea-s

  // position off-screen
  style.position = 'absolute';  // required to return coordinates properly
  style.top = element.offsetTop + parseInt(computed.borderTopWidth) + 'px';
  style.left = "400px";
  style.visibility = mirrorDivDisplayCheckbox.checked ? 'visible' : 'hidden';  // not 'display: none' because we want rendering

  // transfer the element's properties to the div
  properties.forEach(function (prop) {
    style[prop] = computed[prop];
  });

  if (isFirefox) {
    style.width = parseInt(computed.width) - 2 + 'px'  // Firefox adds 2 pixels to the padding - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=753662
    // Firefox lies about the overflow property for textareas: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984275
    if (element.scrollHeight > parseInt(computed.height))
      style.overflowY = 'scroll';
  } else {
    style.overflow = 'hidden';  // for Chrome to not render a scrollbar; IE keeps overflowY = 'scroll'
  }  

  mirrorDiv.textContent = element.value.substring(0, position);
  // the second special handling for input type="text" vs textarea: spaces need to be replaced with non-breaking spaces - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13402035/1269037
  if (element.nodeName === 'INPUT')
    mirrorDiv.textContent = mirrorDiv.textContent.replace(/\s/g, "\u00a0");

  var span = document.createElement('span');
  // Wrapping must be replicated *exactly*, including when a long word gets
  // onto the next line, with whitespace at the end of the line before (#7).
  // The  *only* reliable way to do that is to copy the *entire* rest of the
  // textarea's content into the <span> created at the caret position.
  // for inputs, just '.' would be enough, but why bother?
  span.textContent = element.value.substring(position) || '.';  // || because a completely empty faux span doesn't render at all
  span.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
  mirrorDiv.appendChild(span);

  var coordinates = {
    top: span.offsetTop + parseInt(computed['borderTopWidth']),
    left: span.offsetLeft + parseInt(computed['borderLeftWidth'])
  };

  return coordinates;
}
```

```html
<p>Click anywhere in the text to see a red vertical line &ndash; a 1-pixel div that should be positioned exactly at the location of the caret. Th eposition of the caret will be logged in the console.</p>
<hr>
<input type="text" size="15" maxlength="240" placeholder="Enter text here">

<hr>

<textarea rows="25" cols="40"></textarea>

<br>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mirrorDivDisplay" onchange="toggleMirrorDivDisplay(this)">Show mirror div
</label>
```